Ограничение на макет grid с значением по умолчанию
Описание
Хочу создать такой мает при помощи CSS - Grid:




Насколько нужно для контента
Как можно больше
Насколько нужно для контента, но не больше 30vmin




Как можно больше
menu-area

toolkit-area


Насколько нужно для контента
menu-area
status-area
toolkit-area



Собственно создаю:


div.container {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 'menu-area -1- toolkit-area' 1fr 'menu-area status-area toolkit-area' auto / auto 1fr minmax(auto, 30vmin);
}

div.menu {
  grid-area: menu-area;
  background-color: red;
}

div.status {
  grid-area: status-area;
  background-color: green;
}

div.toolkit {
  grid-area: toolkit-area;
  background-color: blue;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    <img alt="Icon">
  </div>
  <div class="status">
     <img alt="Icon">
  </div>
  <div class="toolkit"></div>
</div>



Проблема в том, что toolkit-area (синяя область) по умолчанию занимает 30vmin, но внутри контента нет.
Поскольку я задал minmax(auto, 30vmin), он почему-то решил, что надо занять 30vmin даже без контента.
Вопрос
Я хочу, чтобы его ширина была столько, сколько понадобиться для контента внутри, но не больше 30vmin, а не 30vmin по умолчанию. Но у меня не удается контролировать размер по-умолчанию. Такие варианты как minmax(0, 30vmin), minmax(min-content, 30vmin) или minmax(max-content, 30vmin) не работают.
Как решить этот вопрос?
Уточнение
Поскольку в области toolkit-area могут быть совершенно разные панели, то есть нельзя задать его размер auto и задать максимальную ширину панелей max-width: 30vmin.
Не будем углубляться, просто примем что так не вариант. :)

а как должно отображаться?

@Grundy так как в синей части нету контента, там ширина должна быть 0, то есть синяя часть не должна отображаться.

Много непонятного в вопросе... Откуда такая любовь к minmax(...) ? Чем не устраивает max-width ? И почему vmin, а не vmax ?
Решение ниже полностью отвечает на сам вопрос, но уточнение идёт вразрез.


div.container {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 'menu-area . toolkit-area' 1fr 'menu-area status-area toolkit-area' auto / auto 1fr min-content;
}

div.menu {
  grid-area: menu-area;
  background-color: red;
}

div.status {
  grid-area: status-area;
  background-color: green;
}

div.toolkit {
  grid-area: toolkit-area;
  background-color: blue;
  max-width: 30vmin;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu" contenteditable>
    <img alt="Icon">
  </div>
  <div class="status" contenteditable>
     <img alt="Icon">
  </div>
  <div class="toolkit" contenteditable>toolkit</div>
</div>



Я специально сделал блоки редактируемыми, чтобы можно было проверить, что всё растягивается и ограничивается, как нужно.

Откуда такая любовь к minmax(...) ? - Любовь не к minmax(...) просто другого выбора нету. Чем не устраивает max-width ? - Мне надо деформировать макет, а не блоки. И почему vmin, а не vmax ? - А почему vmax должно быть?

@eccs0103, давайте по существу. Укажите на неправильное поведение в моём ответе. Все блоки растягиваются по контенту, синий блок имеет ограничение, а без контента схлопывается. Я так понял ваш вопрос.

Я и не говорю, что ваш ответ неправильный, он скорее неполноценный․ Он не учитывает то, что я не смогу задать размеры панелей внутри. И все же я бы хотел узнать в чем vmax предпочтительнее?

@eccs0103, каков вопрос таков и ответ ;-) Вы постоянно говорите про панели, но о чём речь - непонятно. Уточните, добавьте пример. Про vmin - он берётся от высоты или ширины, в зависимости от того, что из них имеет меньший размер. Очевидно, что при вертикальном расположении экрана (или соответствующих размерах окна браузера), блок toolkit будет довольно узким, и ваши "панели" могут не поместиться. Хотя... "Не будем углубляться..."

То, что будет находиться в области toolkit-area я называю панелями. Там могут быть совершенно разные блоки (панели) с разными пропорциями. Мне надо делать макет таким, чтобы он не сломался независимо от пропорции панелей.

@eccs0103, ну, так если пропорции панелей не будут соответствовать ограничениям (которые Вы сами и ставите - 30vmin), то однозначно что-то должно сломаться. Что ломается в моём ответе? Я искренне хочу помочь, но Вы, как партизан на допросе :)

Да, я такой : D
